# pandas - if nan for x number of rows

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'1':[1,2,3,4,5,6], '2':[2,5,6,8,10,NaN], '3':[10,10,10,NaN,NaN,NaN]})
```

I want to be able to say that a row is inactive (but not drop the column/row) if there are 3 at least 3 consecutive NaN. Below is an example of what I am looking to create:

```
y = pd.DataFrame({'1': ['active', 'active', 'active', 'active', 'active', 'active',
    '2': ['active', 'active', 'active', 'active', 'active', 'active'], 
    '3': ['active', 'active', 'active', 'active', 'active', 'inactive']})
```

I have tried using forward fill with an if statement but it did not work.

thanks

Comment: Don't you mean a *row* is inactive? your example still has all original columns.

Comment: edited to say row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `ffill` with `limit`

```
out = x.ffill(limit=2).isna().replace({True:'inactive',False:'active'})
```

Comment: I think you might have flipped the 'active' and 'inactive' terms for `replace`. Unless I misunderstood the output that was wanted.

Comment: @ceruler ah changed ~

Answer (score 0):

Another method that is has a similar approach to BENY but uses `pd.rolling`

```
x = x.rolling(window=3).count()==0

x.replace({True:'inactive',False:'active'})


        1       2         3
0  active  active    active
1  active  active    active
2  active  active    active
3  active  active    active
4  active  active    active
5  active  active  inactive
```